# PHP session expires from android WebService

Tags: php, android, web-services, session-variables

I'm coding an android app that sometimes uses php scripts and I'm now trying to use some Session IDs in the php scripts that I'm using. So when the user loggs (login/pwd) on the webservice from the application a sessionID is created on the webservice/PHP server.

I was wondering what would happend if the session was expired after a moment on the server and that the android device would try to make a request (since it can't know if the session is still working) ? Can the session actually be destroyed if the android httpclient is still in the android app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expired session only marked as a candidate for garbage collection.

Garbage collector is invoked with some probability before each request.

So even though session expiration time has come - this doesn't mean the session will be destroyed immediately. And if it is accessed after the expiration time reached, but before it was removed - the the expiration time counter starts from the beginning.